# dynamic array is allocated without malloc

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, allocation

How did the array get created, even if `malloc` is not used?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n,i,*ptr,sum=0;
    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter elements of array: ");

    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",ptr+i);
        sum+=*(ptr+i);
    }

    printf("Sum=%d",sum);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't `malloc` the pointer before you use it, it *might* not generate a run-time error because the invalid address you're referencing may happen to be within a space that your program has access to without generating an access violation. That doesn't mean it's good. It's still an error. You should turn on warning messages.

Comment: I appreciate this answer,this is interesting ,can you throw more light on ---"the invalid address you're referencing may happen to be within a space that your program has access to without generating an access violation "

Comment: If the address is, for example, within the area where the heap is, that's memory your application is allowed to read or write, but you may not have allocated it properly using `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

The array is not "created". It is declared. Then it is not defined or initialized. You use it.

**Undefined behavior.**

If you used a more stricter compiler, then you would have gotten:

```
 warning: ‘ptr’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

Therefore it is actually not *dynamic*.

The bigger question here in my opinion is what happens with `free(ptr)`:

It is possible, **but** is also **undefined behavior**. Since you pass an uninitialized pointer, the value of the pointer is not clear. It might be by accident `NULL` but not limited to.

The big picture:

Accessing **any** uninitialised variable results in **undefined behavior**.

**EDIT:**

OP didn't declare an *array*, rather an integer pointer.

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, an integer pointer has been declared. But the OP referred to it as an array, that's why I kept it so. I will edit my answer to remove any ambiguities.

Comment: Ok. Good. +1 BTW. Good Answer.